# Is $f(x) = \frac{5x^2}{1+x^2}$ bounded?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> Show that $$f(x) = \frac{5x^2}{1+x^2}$$ is a bounded function?

I know that if $x=0$ the function is undefined, but how can you prove that it is bounded? Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Why do you say it's undefined at $x = 0$?

Comment: A [rational function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function) (such as this) will only be undefined when you have a division by zero error.  Note that $1+x^2\neq 0$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$, implying that the function is in fact defined for all $x$.

Answer (score 10):

We have $\frac{5x^2}{x^2+1}=5-\frac{5}{x^2+1}$. From this it follows that 
$$0\le \frac{5x^2}{x^2+1}\lt 5,$$
so the function is bounded.

Comment: Beat me to it while I was typing this up! +1

Comment: It is worth noting that the origin form makes it obvious that the expression is $\geq 0$ and the second form makes it obvious that the expression is $< 5$

Comment: i don't get how $\frac{5x^2}{x^2+1}=5-\frac{5}{x^2+1}$ is valid. i know it is, but i don't get how.

Comment: You can verify it by just taking the right-hand side and simplifying. Or you can write $\frac{5x^2}{x^2+1}=\frac{5x^2+5-5}{x^2+1}=\frac{5x^2+5}{x^2+1}-\frac{5}{x^2+1}$. Or you can use polynomial "long" division, actually it will be pretty short.  Actually, I think I prefer the answer of R. Freitas.

Answer (score 3):

This function is well defined at $0$ since the denominator is $\ge 1$ at every point of $\mathbb{R}$.

Since $0 < 1$ we have $x^2 < 1+x^2$ for all $x$ thus $\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}<1$ on the whole real line.

Now $$ f(x) = 5 \left[\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}\right] < 5$$

Answer (score 2):

**A possibility:**

Show that the function has a finite limit $\ell$ at both $-\infty$ and $+\infty$. This means that it will have at stay very close to $\ell$ (say, $\ell-1 \leq f(x) \leq \ell+1$) outside some interval of the form $[-A,A]$.

Since it is also continuous, it is bounded within $[-A,A]$. So overall, it is bounded outside $[-A,A]$, and inside $[-A,A]$.

(Also, note that your function is very well defined at $0$. Its value there is $0$ (the numerator is $0$, the denominator $1$).)

Comment: Love the nested parentheses.